# check if function wrote anything?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a function which queries database using a key and writes some data relating to that key. I want to check if there was any result returned but none of these works:

```
function special(key)
    'some code to querying to database and get a result
     response.write result
    'also response.write combination of html and texts and number
    ' if (some conditions) then (also response.write something more)
end function
```

first try:

```
if special("fp") then
 response.write "found"
end if
```

second try:

```
if not(isNull(special("fp"))) then
 response.write "found"
end if
```

Comment: `repsonse.write` writes output to the page. It doesn't make that output the return value of your function. You'd do that with a line `special = result`, or `Set special = result`, depending on whether or not `result` is an object`. What is the type and value of `result` in the first place? Please provide more context.

Comment: I wrote the question with minimum description. In fact the output of this function is not a single string or number. This function writes lots of html and contains if-else inside it. I have updated the question.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough the first time. VBScript functions don't return anything unless you tell them to, by assigning a value to the function name: `Function Foo : Foo = "something" : End Function`. If you just want your function to indicate whether or not your query got a result you could assign it a boolean value depending on the value of `result`: `If ... Then : special = True : Else : special = False : End If`. However, the condition to use there depends on what `result` actually is and how you fill it.

Answer (score 1):

As @Ansgar pointed out, you need your function to return something. So if your function is like:

```
function special(key)
    'some code to querying to database and get a result
     response.write result
    'also response.write combination of html and texts and number
    ' if (some conditions) then (also response.write something more)

    ' to determine if data was returned, you would need the following line. It assumes you have a recordset variable named rs that either returns data or not
    special = rs.BOF and rs.EOF
end function
```

if rs.BOF is true, and RS.eof is true, then no fata was found:

```
if special("fp") then
    Response.Write "no value found"
else
    ' data was found, proceed with whatever happens next on the page
```